# How to make the navigation bar like the one in Pulse?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

[image]

How to make a Pulse-like navigation bar which is scrollable (the area is marked by the rectangle)? Can someone point me an example?

Thanks
Lvreiny

Comment: i do accept every answers which solve my problems. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually simple. Just nest scroll views. The outer one covers the whole screen and only allowing vertical scrolling.

Each series of thumbnails is contained in another, smaller scroll view which only allows horizontal scrolling. I've used this technique myself for an app I was contracted to develop.

Your navigation bar can be a horizontal scrollview right at the top with `UIButtons` in them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Three20** project on github have a tabbar like you example.

Here code: https://github.com/facebook/three20

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would create it with a scrollbar with an overlay view for the fade effect at the edges.